# Show relations in a group presentation hold "as non-trivially as possible"

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

To simplify notation, I will state the question in a less general form. I suspect the answer I'm looking for will be easily extended to the general case that I'm interested in.

Let $S$ be a collection of symbols and $u,v$ be two words in $S \sqcup S^{-1}$.
Define two groups via the presentations $$G = \langle S \mid u,v \rangle \text{ and }H = \langle S \mid uv \rangle.$$ I want to show that $G$ is not isomorphic to $H$. I've tried using the fact that there's an epimorphism $H \to G$ which extends the inclusion map $S \hookrightarrow G$, but I haven't been able to proceed from this.

Comment: Let's start with some counterexamples. First one: $u$ = empty word, $v$ anything. Second one: $u$ arbitrary, $v=u^{-2}$. So you need some restrictions on $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Thanks! Would the statement be true if we assume that $u,v$ are reduced, non-empty words and $u$ is not equal to $v^{-1}$?

Comment: In my counterexample we had $v=u^{-2}$, not $v=u^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a less trivial counterexample. A non-Hopfian group is one that is isomorphic to a proper quotient of itself.

Well known examples include the Baumslag-Solitar groups
$${\rm BS}(m,n) = \langle x,y \mid y^{-1}x^myx^{-n} \rangle$$
for various values on $m$ and $n$.

In particular, ${\rm BS}(2,3)$ is non-Hopfian and if we let $w=y^{-1}x^2yx^{-3}$ and $v = (x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)^2x^{-1}$, then
$$\langle x,y \mid w \rangle \cong \langle x,y \mid w,v \rangle.$$
So we get a counterexample to your question by taking $u=wv^{-1}$.

I was wondering whether the natural epimorphism $\langle S \mid u,v \rangle  \to \langle S \mid uv \rangle$ has nontrivial kernel except in a few obvious cases, but that will not work either.

If the relator $v$ is a consequence of the relator $w$, then we can do the same thing. For example, we could take $w = [x,y]$ and $v = [x^2,y]$.

Comment: +1 I was half way through writing up a basically identical answer!

Comment: Thanks for that great answer. And yes, now I see what's happening. If $\langle S \mid uv \rangle$ *is* Hopfian and $\langle S \mid uv \rangle \simeq \langle S \mid u,v \rangle $, then the natural map  $\langle S \mid uv \rangle \to \langle S \mid u,v \rangle $ necessarily has trivial kernel. Assuming that $u$ or $v$ is non-trivial in $\langle S \mid uv \rangle$, this leads to a contradiction. However, if the group is non-Hopfian, or both $u$ and $v$ are trivial in this group, then the argument goes out of the window.

Comment: The only thing I can't figure out in your example is how to reduce $v = (x^{-1}y^{-1}xy)^2x^{-1}$ to the trivial word using the relation $y^{-1}x^2yx^{-3} = 1$. Could you clarify?

Comment: The whole point is that $w=1$ does NOT imply that $v=1$ in hte ${\rm BS}(2,3)$ example. The group is non-Hopfian, and $\langle x,y \mid w,v \rangle$ is a proper quotient of $\langle x,y \mid w \rangle$.

Comment: I see. How does one show that $\langle x,y  \mid w \rangle$ and $\langle x,y \mid w,v \rangle$ (from your example) are isomorphic?

Comment: @3891780 This is "well known". Its pretty straightforward to prove though, via Tietze transformations. Roughly, start with $\langle x, y\mid w, v\rangle$ and add in $z=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$ and then try to eliminate $x$ by replacing it with $z^2$. You can find a proof on p260 of Magnus, Karrass and Solitar's book "Combinatorial group theory".